# Can a function in sh have zero statements?

Tags: shell, function, posix, syntax

Are there any relevant standards that dictate what an implementation of `sh` must do with an empty function?

The following snippet defines a function with zero statements

```
a() {
}
```

The subshell version appears to be treated identically

```
a() (
)
```

`ash` and `zsh` accept either construction as a function that does nothing and has an exit status of zero.

`ksh` (`ksh93`) and `bash` both reject this function as a syntax error

```
$ a() {
> }
ksh: syntax error: `}' unexpected
```

and with bash

```
bash-4.4$ a() {
> }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, a function may not have an empty body between braces in a conforming application.

---

POSIX [defines a function definition command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05) as:

```
fname ( ) compound-command [io-redirect ...]
```

where all those words are placeholders for things defined elsewhere in the specification. `compound-command` is the body of the function.

A [*compound command* is defined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) as one of several items, including loops, conditionals, and case statements, but most relevantly here as [a *grouping command*, which is defined in two cases](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01):

> `( compound-list )`
>
> Execute compound-list in a subshell environment; see Shell Execution Environment. Variable assignments and built-in commands that affect the environment shall not remain in effect after the list finishes. (*... passage about arithmetic expansion elided ...*)
>
> `{ compound-list ; }`
>
> Execute compound-list in the current process environment. The semicolon shown here is an example of a control operator delimiting the } reserved word. Other delimiters are possible, as shown in Shell Grammar; a <newline> is frequently used.

An empty `{\n}` body would be valid if `compound-list` could be empty.

The [Shell Grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10) in turn defines the parsing rules of the shell command language, including *compound_list*:

> ```
> compound_list    : linebreak term
>                  | linebreak term separator
> ```

This means a compound list is either `linebreak` followed by a `term`, or `linebreak` followed by a `term` and a `separator`. `separator` is `;` or `&`. `linebreak` is a possibly-empty sequence of newlines. So this can be empty if `term` can be empty.

`term` is:

> ```
> term             : term separator and_or
>                  |                and_or
> ```

and `and_or`:

> ```
> and_or           :                         pipeline
>                  | and_or AND_IF linebreak pipeline
>                  | and_or OR_IF  linebreak pipeline
> ```

The last two lines cover `&&` and `||`. `pipeline` is a non-empty sequence of `command`s separated by `|` characters. `command` is a simple command, a compound command, or a function definition. So `term`, and `command`, can be empty if either simple or compound commands can be empty.

A simple command always includes one of `cmd_name`, `cmd_word`, or `cmd_prefix`. `cmd_prefix` is either a redirect or an assignment, optionally attached to another prefix. The other two both break down to `WORD`, a token in the grammar that is a non-empty sequence of word characters. So a simple command is never empty.

We've looked at compound commands already, but let's circle back from the perspective of the grammar this time. A compound command is one of a brace group, subshell, `for`, `while`, or `until` loop, and `if`, or a `case`. All of these contain a fixed word (like "`for`") or a `(` or `{` at minimum. So a compound command is never empty.

Thus a `command` is never empty, so `pipeline` is never empty, nor `and_or`, `term`, or `compound_list`. That means that

```
{
}
```

is not permitted, and so the function definition

```
a() {
}
```

is not valid either.

---

All of the above applies for a conforming, portable shell script. `zsh` and `ash` are free to extend their implementations to handle otherwise-invalid scripts however they want, and the implementation they've chosen seems sensible and convenient. Bash, ksh, dash, and others have taken the more minimalistic route of implementing what was required. All of these are conformant choices.

A portable script will always need to provide a non-empty function body, but a script targeting (say) zsh alone does not.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are interested in the syntax tree for various shells. Here's the relevant section for bash: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Syntax

Functions are defined as [[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions)]:

> Functions are declared using this syntax:
>     `name () compound-command [ redirections ]`
>   or
>     `function name [()] compound-command [ redirections ]`

The part you are interested in is the `compound-command`, which can be one of the following [[2](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Compound-Commands)]:

> • Looping Constructs:     Shell commands for iterative action.
>   • Conditional Constructs:     Shell commands for conditional execution.
>   • Command Grouping:       Ways to group commands.

The `{}` and `()` syntax are a `command grouping` which can be one of the following [[3](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)]:

> `( list )`
>   `{ list; }`

A `list` is defined as [[4](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)]:

> A list is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators `‘;’`, `‘&’`, `‘&&’`, or `‘||’`, and optionally terminated by one of `‘;’`, `‘&’`, or a newline.

A `pipline` is defined as [[5](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines)]:

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators `‘|’` or `‘|&’`.

Your function examples contain a compound-command, which must contain one or more `pipelines`, which each contain one or more `commands`.

Therefore, in bash, you must have at least one command in your function. The other shells are probably similar, and have their syntax guides readily available as well.

If for some reason you want to have a function that does nothing, you can use Bash's placeholder built-in, which is `:` -- it does nothing successfully.

```
a(){:}
```

Comment: Other fun variations; `a() (())` and `a() (:)` and (ksh93, not bash) `a() {;}`

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest to empty that bash gets:

```
a (){  
  :   
}
```